# Why is `--` converted into ndash and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: html-editor, wp-kses, htmlspecialchars-decode

I have a blog where I publish Linux tutorials. Some of the commands I listed have a `--` before command-line arguments. e.g.: `dpkg --get-selections`.

The problem is that WordPress automatically switches `--` to an – (`&ndash;`).

I know I could use the `&minus;&minus;` HTML entities, but the display is slightly different than the keyboard `-` sign.

What I want is to disable this behaviour of WP. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Update: The function responsible for this is wptexturize... line 73 in formatting.php ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with this gist https://gist.github.com/4329321 .

`[notexturize]--[/notexturize]` worked like a charm.